# Pyomo: How to impose the constraint that the decision variables must be a multiple of a specific integer?

Tags: python, optimization, integer, pyomo

I am making an AbstractModel in Pyomo and I want to impose as a constraint the following:

- My decision variables are Xij, defined as: model.x = Var(model.I, model.J, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
- The constraint is that Xij must be zero or a multiple of 50.

I am trying to do so by using the remainder but when making the constraint with % or something similar I obtain that % does not support using int.

How would you propose this constraint?

Example:

[Example of constraint that I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVRYB.png)

Comment: Please insert your code directly into the question instead of linking to an external image, because, first, people trying out your example cannot copy it and, second, external links may vanish some day making this question useless for others.

Answer (score 1):

"Xij must be zero or a multiple of 50"

```
 variables
    y(i,j) ∈ {0,1,2,3...}
    x(i,j) ≥ 0
 constraint
    x(i,j) = 50*y(i,j)
```